# where are questions for a Microsoft Azure QnA bot stored?

Tags: email, azure, bots, skype

I run a QnA bot (Animal-Rights-Bot) that answers questions via skype or email but there is a discrepancy between the number of questions shown in the Azure dahsboard and the bot mailbox. I`m wondering where I find those questions that were sent to the bot in Skype and per Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get all the chatlogs from QnAMaker in the test tab on the portal. There is a download chat logs link.

Comment: Thank you Prashant, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Every knowledge base content is stored in Azure storage by the QnAMaker tool. You need a combination of knowledge base id and subscription key to access the knowledge base. The knowledge base contents are not used by the tool for any other purpose.

Here is the API reference documentation for the the QnA maker . you can use them to programmatically query the knowledge base.

https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/ApiReference

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I am not familiar with coding and am trying to use the Azure STorage Explorer but still don´t see the chat logs in the blob container

Comment: @AnimalsarenotThings probably it is not stored in your subscription since this is offered as a service it will be stored in some central repository safely. That is why you have API to access that data.